# Python Virtualenv importing utils

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm running Python 2.7.4 on Ubuntu 13.04 and try to set up a virtualenv. I had to install some modules with pip to run the code but I'm not able to install utils which is used for parse_date.

This is what I get:

```
$ pip install utils
Downloading/unpacking utils
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement utils
No distributions at all found for utils
```

What should I do now?

Comment: What is "utils"? Please, provide error message, generated by parse_date call.

Comment: I doubt there's a module named "utils" (there's lot that contain it though). Maybe it's a local module that isn't on PyPi that you're missing?

Comment: the code Im trying to run is not written by me. so Im not sure... this is the import: from utils import parse_date

Comment: @Chromos Then it might be local. Do a recursive search in the source folder and see if it may be laying around, or check if you have all the source code. There is no offical module on the Python Package Indexer (PyPi, used for pip) named 'util'.

Comment: @timss ok thx! I will see what I can find

Comment: @Chromos Note that every Python file can be used as a module, so if there's a file named 'util.py', that could be it, even if there's no classes or anything in it. That is also why there's a pretty good chance there's a local module. (updated because edit was freezed).

Comment: @timss I actually found a utils.py but it doesnt contain any function like parse_date...

Comment: @Chromos In that case I'd try to contact the developer or check any documentation if available.

Answer (score -1):

you can first to do some seeking, like:

```
pip search utils
```

then find one to install.